# UPDATE query methods must either return void or int (the number of updated rows) while trying to return Flow<Int>

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Koltin version : **1.6.21.**

Room dependencies :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.4.2"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.2"
```

Here is the query method :

```
@Query("UPDATE releve SET accuracy_indicator = :isEnabled WHERE id_local = :releveId")
    fun updateAccuracyIndicator(releveId: Long, isEnabled: Boolean): Flow<Int>
```

I don't know how to handle this issue ?

Comment: Can you show your offending query method?

Comment: make sens it's just needed to be a suspend function. as it's only one shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update operation is a one-shot so it should return a single Int rather than a flow of Ints. You can make the return type Int, and you can optionally mark the function `suspend` so it won’t block the caller.