# how to fix UPDATE query methods

Tags: android, sql, database, kotlin, dao

How to fix this error in Dao kotlin query.

> UPDATE query methods must either return void or int (the number of
> updated rows).

```
public abstract java.lang.Object update(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
```

Correct answers from other developers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPDATE query methods must either return void or int (the number of updated rows) while trying to return Flow<Int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455438/update-query-methods-must-either-return-void-or-int-the-number-of-updated-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning java.lang.Object, but according to error message you should be returning null or int.

```
public abstract int update(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable)
```

or

```
public abstract void update(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable)
```

Should work. Your method should return void or int, depending on your declaration.